# trying to connect to mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection

I'm trying to connect to my database. I added the MySQL connector driver jar by

- creating a folder called lib
- Putting the jar inside lib
- Right Clicking on the project >> Properties >> build path >> (going inside the libraries tab) >> adding jar

my code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world", "user", "pass");
        Statement myStat = myConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet myRs = myStat.executeQuery("Select * from city");
        while (myRs.next()) {
            System.out.println(myRs.getString("Name"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

ERROR:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at javademo4.driver.main(driver.java:8)
```

I'm using Eclipse Luna and mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar. I also definitely have a database called world and a table called city which has a column called Name

Comment: "It still doesn't work" isn't very helpful to us. What error do you get?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've included the error now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to register your mysql driver, add this line above the `Connection` line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`

Hope it helps